# iTunesConnect - download numbers for more then 10 apps?

Tags: app-store-connect

Is there a way in Apple's iTunesConnect to find out how many downloads all apps have? I get the numbers for our top ten apps in "Sales & Trends", but I can't find the numbers for the other apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you were looking for: https://appfigures.com

It's an uber awesome, extremely useful app to track your overall app downloads & sales!

Comment: Wow, that is uber awesome. Thx!